# jQuery $(this) does not insert text into my element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently adding flagging functionality to a project of mine, and I can't get jQuery's `$(this)` selector to work.

The goal of this is to change the text in the `div` from `flag` to `flagged` when the user clicks it, and the ajax query runs successfully. My HTML/PHP is:

```
<div class="flag" post_to_flag='".$post_to_flag."'>Flag</div>
```

And my javascript that deals with the `div` is:

```
$('.flag').live('click', function () {
    $.post('../php/core.inc.php', {
        action: 'flag',
        post_to_flag: $(this).attr('post_to_flag')
    }, function (flag_return) {
        if (flag_return == 'query_success') {
            $(this).text('flagged');
        } else {
            alert(flag_return);
        }
    });
});
```

I can't replace the text with `flagged`, but if I replace the `this` selector with the `.flag` selector, it will replace everything with the class of flag on the page.

I have checked, and the `$(this)` selector is getting the attribute of 'post_to_flag' just fine. Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should add a context variable:

```
$('.flag').live('click', function () {
    var $context = $(this);
    $.post('../php/core.inc.php', {
        action: 'flag',
        post_to_flag: $context.attr('post_to_flag')
    }, function (flag_return) {
        if (flag_return == 'query_success') {
            $context.text('flagged');
        } else {
            alert(flag_return);
        }
    });
});
```

You are calling multiple functions within your `jQuery` selection call. When you go into that `$.post()` function, your scope changes. `this` now refers to a different scope from when you were inside `one()`.

@Moak's suggestion, if you set a variable to a jQuery object, it's probably best to denote the variable with a beginning `$` just for potential clarity for future readers or yourself.

Comment: I'd also suggest prefixing the variable with `$` e.g. `$context` or `$this` to indicate that the value is a jQuery object

Comment: @Moak, yes! You can definitely do that, it would help clarify it's a jQuery object. I'll change it up.

Answer (score 1):

`this` inside the ajax callback is not the element, but it is the Ajax object itself.

You can use `$.proxy` to pass in the context.

[Ref $.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

```
$('.flag').live('click', function () {
$.post('../php/core.inc.php', 
      {action: 'flag', post_to_flag: $(this).attr('post_to_flag')},    
    $.proxy(function(flag_return) {
       if(flag_return == 'query_success'){
         $(this).text('flagged'); //Now this here will represent .flag
       }else{
         alert(flag_return);
       }
    },this)); //Now here you are passing in the context of `.flag`
```